# Sphinx autodoc not importing module.submodule but importing module

Tags: python, anaconda, python-sphinx

(*I have been browsing among the Sphinx autodoc related answers for a while now but I have not been able to find a solution (nor a bug report, if it is the case) for this. Please feel free to point to an already answer if that is the case, in any way I would highly appreciate some help.*)

I am using Sphinx to document some python project on Anaconda, and as other answers suggest I have added all the suggested lines into my config.py:

```py
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
```

I know this is working properly since for one the modules the documentation is built correctly, and it has the lines:

```py
import scipy as sp
sp.optimize.curve_fit(my_funct, x, y)
```

However, when using:

```py
import scipy.optimize as op
op.curve_fit(my_funct, x, y)
```

or

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
curve_fit(my_funct, x, y)
```

The build fails, giving:

```
  File "C:\my_module.py", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy.optimize as op
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.optimize'
```

Am I supposed to used every imported functions calling all the modules structure (i.e. sp.optimize.curve_fit) whenever using autodoc?

Is there some additional set up I have missed?

---

I have encounter the same problem with other packages (both default python and user created) so I know the problem is not package specific.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Scipy. Do you have an example of a "default python" package that exhibits the problem?

Comment: I also get this when using `from numpy.random import normal`.

Comment: OK. Maybe I misunderstood what you mean by "default python" package. I thought that you were referring to Python standard library modules. Can you reproduce the problems using the standard Python distribution (not Anaconda)?

Comment: It seems to be with Anaconda packages. I tired with `from urllib.request import urlcleanup` and got a successful build.

Comment: @mzjn is there anything I can provide you with so that you can maybe replicate?